# Karate json key list variable assignment

Tags: karate

New to Karate, and JSON, for that matter, but I've got a variable like:

```
response {
  entries {
    products [
      {
        names [
          "Peter Parker",
          "Tony Stark",
          "Captain America"
        ]
      },
      {
        names [
          "Thomas Tinker",
          "Jimmy Johnson",
          "Mama Martha"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`match each response.entries.products[*].names` returns a list like:

```
["Peter Parker","Tony Stark","Captain America","Thomas Tinker","Jimmy Johnson","Mama Martha"]
```

But I'd like to assign that output to a variable, such as:

`* def variable = response.entries.products[*].names`

that would hold a similar value. When I use the above line, I get the following error:

```
Expected an operand but found *
```

Is it possible to achieve that, or something similar? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is syntax for that:

```
* def variable = $response.entries.products[*].names
```

Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#get